# Как включить мобильный интернет на Android

Tags: java, android, сеть, mobile

Мне нужно программно включить мобильный интернет. Wifi можно включить через WifiManager, а как включить мобильный интернет?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такой способ:

```
public void setMobileDataState(boolean mobileDataEnabled) {
      try {
         TelephonyManager telephonyService = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
         Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = Objects.requireNonNull(telephonyService).getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setDataEnabled", boolean.class);
         setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(telephonyService, mobileDataEnabled);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
         Log.e("MainActivity", "Error setting mobile data state", ex);
      }
   }
```

чтобы проверить состояние сети используйте данную функцию:

```
public boolean getMobileDataState() {
      try {
         TelephonyManager telephonyService = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
         Method getMobileDataEnabledMethod = Objects.requireNonNull(telephonyService).getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getDataEnabled");
         return (boolean) (Boolean) getMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(telephonyService);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
         Log.e("MainActivity", "Error getting mobile data state", ex);
      }
      return false;
   }
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120082/latest-update-on-enabling-and-disabling-mobile-data-programmatically) подобный вопрос_1, и вот [вопрос_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539445/the-setmobiledataenabled-method-is-no-longer-callable-as-of-android-l-and-later), ну и [доки](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing) само собой :) Не забудьте проверить в манифесте наличие разрешений.

Comment: А зачем рефлексия, можно же просто вызвать метод?

Comment: да можно и просто метод вызвать тоже